# Python - subsetting WRF data on curvilinear map

Tags: python, weather

I have a WRF output that is on a curvilinear projection (native lambert conformal projection), therefore there are 2D coordinates (XLONG & XLAT) associated with it.  I am able to subset the data into a rectangular grid by slicing the array

e.g.

xlat = constants.variables['XLAT'][0,749:915,220:458]

xlon = constants.variables['XLONG'][0,749:915,220:458]

However, I want to subset all the grid points that are bounded by specific latitudes and longitudes to get a sort of trapezoid shape of grid points.  I have attached an image to make it easy to understand.  I want the grid points bounded by the red line, instead of the grid points within the blue box.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxnhuhyoena8a8e/WRF_StudySites.pdf?dl=0

This can be done in NCL (NCAR command line) using the where() function but I am having trouble doing the same thing in python.

Any tips on how I could possibly do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I find the `xarray` package works quite well with WRF output. Perhaps you could use its [`where`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#masking-with-where) function to create a mask for the coordinates?

Comment: Thanks @Peter9192.  Looks like a great package.  I've tried subsetting using xr.where() by using the conditional statement 

lat_min= 49.
lat_max= 53.
lon_min = -113.
lon_max = -125.

(lat>lat_min) & (lat<lat_max) & (lon >lon_min) & (lon<lon_max).  I then use that to subset temperature, but I seem to just get all masked values.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me, see my answer below for details. If you need more help you should copy some of your code and perhaps also example data, otherwise I can't offer any more help.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `xarray` package for this. See [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#masking-with-where) for the explanation of its `where()` function. The longitude in my dataset ranges from -5 to 13, so conditioning that XLONG>0 returns only part of my data (as intended).

For example:

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load dataset with xarray (I only import T2 here, and only the first time)
wrftemp = xr.open_dataset('wrfout_d01_.....').T2.isel(Time=1)

# Make a figure of the T2 temperature field
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
wrftemp.plot(ax=ax1)
wrftemp.where(wrftemp.XLONG>0).plot(ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```